# capistrano 3 (ruby) variable scope

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

I have some problems with a capistrano 3 script regarding the scope of variables. I read the variables from hiera like this:

```
deployment = hiera("deployment")
deployment.each_pair{|k,v|
   binding.eval("#{k}='#{v}'")
}
```

My hiera file looks like this:

```
---
deployment:
  webserver_group: 'www-data'
  app_config_environment: 'prod'
  application: 'site_manager'
  translator_deploymentLockPath: '/tmp/translation_lockfile.lock'
```

If I try to access the variables in a task I receive an error message like this:

> Exception while executing on host xxxx: undefined local variable or
>   method `translator_deploymentLockPath' for

Here is how a task looks like:

```
desc "creates a new lockfile"
task :create_lock do
   on roles(:app), in: :parallel do
     execute :touch, "#{translator_deploymentLockPath}"
   end
 end
```

If I declare the variables global (like this: `binding.eval("$#{k}='#{v}'")` ) I can read them in the tasks using `$translator_deploymentLockPath` instead of `#{translator_deploymentLockPath}` but this is not a solution for me because I have a lot of code to modify.

What am I missing? How can I read the variables from hiera (using eyaml backend) and declare them so I can use them in my tasks?

Comment: Where is your first code sample located in the project? I'd probably wrap the hiera deployment code in a module so that you have a global class constant instead of a pile of globals.

Comment: My first code sample is located right at the beginning of the script. I do not undestand why when using binding the variables are not accessable in the tasks.